# Laravel use many before filter in route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

in laravel route i want to use many action in `before` for example :

```
Route::resource  ('admin/contents', 'ContentManagmentController' , array('as'=>'contents'));
```

i want to have :

```
'before'=>'csrf'
'before'=>'checkAjax'
```

how to fix this route:is this correct?

```
Route::resource  ('admin/contents', 'ContentManagmentController' , array('as'=>'contents', 'before'=>'csrf','checkAjax'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax:

```
array('as'=>'contents', 'before'=>'csrf','checkAjax');
```

Won't work as you expect it will. It will produce the array:

```
array(
    'as' => 'contents',
    'before' => 'csrf',
    '0' => 'checkAjax',
)
```

See [Laravel Routing: Attaching Multiple Filters to a Route](http://laravel.com/docs/routing):

You may use multiple filters by separating them with a bar `|` character in a single string.
Therefore:

```
array('as'=>'contents', 'before' => 'csrf|checkAjax');
```

Would be the correct solution.

Edit:

Alternatively, you may pass an array instead. E.g.

```
array('as'=>'contents', 'before' => array('csrf', 'checkAjax'));
```

Would also be just as valid.